# data in onActivityResult is null

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying do a simple application for `Android`. I have two Activities (`A` and `B`). In `B` I only want select a `date`.

I start `A`, and do:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent();
 intent.setClass(this, B.class);
 startActivityForResult(intent,1);
```

Then, in `B`, I do:

```
 Intent intent = getIntent();
 setResult(RESULT_OK);
 intent.putExtra("Date",dateSelected);
 finish();
```

And, in `A`, i have the next method:

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
     super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
     if(resultCode==RESULT_OK && requestCode==1){
        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        String aux = bundle.getString("nuevo");
        .....
    }
```

But `data`, and `bundle`, are `null`. When i debug the code, i see that in class `B`, `intent` has the `Extras`, but then, when i call `finish()` and return to `class A`, this `intent` is not reachable.

How can i solve this problem?

Comment: Is there a reason the key name in activity B different than the key name in the onActivityResult() method in activity A?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

try this:

Then, in B, I do:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
intent.putExtra("Date",dateSelected);
setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
finish();
```

And, in A:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode==1) {
        Bundle MBuddle = data.getExtras();
        String MMessage = MBuddle.getString("Date");
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks!!! i needed to change setResult(RESULT_OK, intent). it´s easy, but i am new in android programming.

Comment: @Nobelisco : it's ok always welcome friend.if you have any other issue just comment

Comment: setResult(RESULT_OK, intent); It helped me

Comment: I am doing the exact as your answer says even if I am getting the data.getData()  as null...

Comment: still reciving null

Comment: i am doing the same, i see intent data's mMap with key value pairs that i have put. But when i come back to A's onActivityResult i see intent data->Extras-> mMap as null.

Answer (score 8):

in `A` onActivityResult method

```
   if(null!=data){

    Bundle bundle = data.getExtras();
    String mydate = bundle.getString("Date");

   }
```

and in `B`

```
Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
returnIntent.putExtra("Date",dateSelected);
setResult(RESULT_OK,returnIntent);      
finish();
```

Comment: +1 @SamirMangroliya it's depend on Nobelisco which answer accept or not

Comment: i have no any problem for that but i sometime accept and unaccept then accept then unaccept !!! lolz...

Comment: sorry. i changed my select because i thought the other answer was more explicity. It is true that your answer was more early, but i don´t saw it in that moment. I tried to choose both answers, but it isn´t possible. Thank for you help, and sorry if i did bad.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is answered, but just to give more explanation on the error, you were using `getIntent()` instead of the `data` element received on the callback.

`getIntent()` returns the Intent that was originally used to open **Activity A** (maybe when you opened the app or from another activity), and `data` is the intent that **Activity B** returned as response parameters.

Also, you were using `getIntent()` in **Activity B** instead of creating a new Intent that would be returned to Activity A.

```
Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
```

Finally, the created intent must be added in `setResult`

```
setResult(RESULT_OK,returnIntent);
```