# Getting NullPointerException while picking Picture From Gallery

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

HI i am new to Android and i am trying to save a picture onto a server but as soon as i click on my imageview and get into the gallery and select the picture my App gets crashed and it gives me this Error :

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'java.lang.Object android.os.Bundle.get(java.lang.String)' on a null
>   object reference

**My Activity Code :**

```
    public class ProfileActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    private static int LOAD_IMAGE = 1;
    public RadioGroup profileRadioGroup;
    String imagePath;
    private EditText profileName, profileDob;
    private CircleImageView profileImageView;
    private Button profileSave;
    private RadioButton genderMale, genderFemale;
    private String profileGender;
    private boolean doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false;
    private TelephonyManager telephoneManager;
    private NetworkUtil networkUtil;
    private Bitmap bitmap;
    private SharePrefUtil prefUtil;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);
        getSupportActionBar().hide();
        networkUtil = new NetworkUtil(getApplicationContext());
        telephoneManager = (TelephonyManager) this.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        prefUtil = new SharePrefUtil(getApplicationContext());
        initScreen();
        fillLayout();
    }

    private void initScreen() {
        profileImageView = (CircleImageView) findViewById(R.id.displayprofileimage);
        profileImageView.setOnClickListener(new ButtonClick());

        profileName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.fed_profilename);
        InputFilter[] FilterArray1 = new InputFilter[1];
        FilterArray1[0] = new InputFilter.LengthFilter(30);
        profileName.setFilters(FilterArray1);

        profileDob = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.fed_profileDob);
        profileDob.setFocusable(false);

        profileDob.setOnClickListener(new ButtonClick());

        profileRadioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioSex);
        genderMale = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.gender_male);
        genderFemale = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.gender_female);

        profileSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_profilesave);
        profileSave.setOnClickListener(new ButtonClick());
    }

    private void fillLayout(){
        Log.d("jagteraho","profileImage: "+prefUtil.getValueFromSharePref("profileImage"));
        if(!prefUtil.getValueFromSharePref("profileImage").equalsIgnoreCase("")
                &&!prefUtil.getValueFromSharePref("profileImage").equalsIgnoreCase("null"))
        {
            byte[] encodeByte = Base64.decode(prefUtil.getValueFromSharePref("profileImage"), Base64.DEFAULT);
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(encodeByte, 0, encodeByte.length);
            profileImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
        else{
            profileImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.profile2);
        }
        if (!prefUtil.getValueFromSharePref("profileName").equalsIgnoreCase("null")) {
            profileName.setText(prefUtil.getValueFromSharePref("profileName"));
        }
        if (!prefUtil.getValueFromSharePref("profileGender").equalsIgnoreCase("null")) {
            if (prefUtil.getValueFromSharePref("profileGender").equalsIgnoreCase("male"))
                genderMale.setChecked(true);
            else if (prefUtil.getValueFromSharePref("profileGender").equalsIgnoreCase("female")) {
                genderFemale.setChecked(true);
            }
        }
        if (!prefUtil.getValueFromSharePref("profileDob").equalsIgnoreCase("null")) {
            profileDob.setText(prefUtil.getValueFromSharePref("profileDob"));
        }
    }

    /**
     * used for display profile picture from the gallery.
     */
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {

            bitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data"); //I am Getting Error At This LIne
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            int index = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            imagePath = cursor.getString(index);
            cursor.close();
            profileImageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath));
        }
    }

    /**
     * save the user profile using the active android database library.
     */
    private void saveProfile() {
        prefUtil.setValueInSharePref("profileName",profileName.getText().toString());
        prefUtil.setValueInSharePref("profileDob", profileDob.getText().toString());
        if (genderFemale.isChecked()) {
            prefUtil.setValueInSharePref("profileGender", "Female");
        } else if (genderMale.isChecked()) {
            prefUtil.setValueInSharePref("profileGender", "Male");
        }
        if(imagePath!=null) {
            prefUtil.setValueInSharePref("profileImage", imagePath);
        }
    }



    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePickerDialog view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {

        String date = "" + year + "-" + (monthOfYear + 1) + "-" + dayOfMonth;
        profileDob.setText(date);
    }

    /**
     * used to call gallery, onclick to profile imageView.
     */
    class ButtonClick implements View.OnClickListener {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch(v.getId())
            {
                case R.id.displayprofileimage:
                    displayProfileImageClicked();
                    break;
                case R.id.btn_profilesave:
                    btnProfileSaveClicked();
                    break;
                case R.id.fed_profileDob:
                    btnProfileDOBClicked();
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    private void displayProfileImageClicked(){
        Intent a = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(a, LOAD_IMAGE);
    }

    private void btnProfileDOBClicked() {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

        cal.set(2005, 12, 31);
        DatePickerDialog dpd = DatePickerDialog.newInstance(
                ProfileActivity.this,
                2005, 12, 31
        );

        dpd.setMaxDate(cal);
        dpd.show(getFragmentManager(), "Datepickerdialog");
    }

    private void btnProfileSaveClicked(){

        if (validateProfile()) {
            try {
                if(genderFemale.isChecked())
                profileGender = genderFemale.getText().toString();
                else
                profileGender = genderMale.getText().toString();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(this, "Please select a gender", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            if (profileGender == null) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Please select a gender", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                if (networkUtil.isConnected()) {
                    profileService();
                } else {
                    android.app.AlertDialog.Builder alertbox = new android.app.AlertDialog.Builder(ProfileActivity.this);
                    alertbox.setMessage("No network connection, Please try after some time");
                    alertbox.create();
                    alertbox.setCancelable(false);
                    alertbox.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });
                    alertbox.show();
                }
            }
        }

    }

    /**
     * class provide all the information of user to server and
     * getting a authentication key as response.
     */
    private void profileService(){
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        String requestURL = String.format(getResources().getString(R.string.service_profileCreate));
        String proImg = null;
        if(imagePath!=null) {
            try {

                File f = new File(imagePath);
                FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(f);
                byte[] data = new byte[fin.available()];
                fin.read(data);
                fin.close();
                proImg = Base64.encodeToString(data, Base64.NO_WRAP);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        JSONObject jsonRequest = new JSONObject();
        try {
            jsonRequest.accumulate("empAuthKey", prefUtil.getValueFromSharePref("authKey"));
            jsonRequest.accumulate("profileImg", proImg);
            jsonRequest.accumulate("name", profileName.getText().toString().trim());
            jsonRequest.accumulate("strDOB", profileDob.getText().toString().trim());
            jsonRequest.accumulate("gender", profileGender);
            jsonRequest.accumulate("mobileNo", prefUtil.getValueFromSharePref("mobileno"));
            jsonRequest.accumulate("imei", telephoneManager.getDeviceId());
        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8"), jsonRequest.toString());
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(requestURL)
                .post(body).build();

        final SweetAlertDialog pDialog = new SweetAlertDialog(ProfileActivity.this, cn.pedant.SweetAlert.SweetAlertDialog.PROGRESS_TYPE);
        pDialog.getProgressHelper().setBarColor(Color.parseColor("#A5DC86"));
        pDialog.setTitleText("Saving Please wait ...");
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();

        client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            String status, message;
            Handler handler = new Handler(new Handler.Callback() {
                @Override
                public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
                    if (msg.what == 1) {
                        Toast.makeText(ProfileActivity.this, "" + message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else if (msg.what == 0) {
                        Toast.makeText(ProfileActivity.this, "" + message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else if (msg.what == -1) {
                        Toast.makeText(ProfileActivity.this, "" + message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else if (msg.what == 2) {
                        Toast.makeText(ProfileActivity.this, "System Error Please try again...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                if (pDialog.isShowing()) pDialog.dismiss();
                handler.sendEmptyMessage(2);
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    String responseString = response.body().string();
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(responseString);
                        status = jsonResponse.getString("status");
                        message = jsonResponse.getString("message");
                        Log.d("jagteraho", "status: " + status + " message: " + message);

                        if (status.equals("success")) {
                            if (pDialog.isShowing()) pDialog.dismiss();
                            saveProfile();
                            handler.sendEmptyMessage(1);
                            Intent login = new Intent(ProfileActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                            startActivity(login);
                            finish();

                        } else if (status.equalsIgnoreCase("failure")) {
                            if (pDialog.isShowing()) pDialog.dismiss();
                            handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
                            Intent profile = new Intent(ProfileActivity.this, ProfileActivity.class);
                            startActivity(profile);
                            finish();

                        } else if (status.equalsIgnoreCase("error")) {
                            if (pDialog.isShowing()) pDialog.dismiss();
                            handler.sendEmptyMessage(-1);
                            Intent alarm = new Intent(ProfileActivity.this, ProfileActivity.class);
                            startActivity(alarm);
                            finish();

                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        if (pDialog.isShowing()) pDialog.dismiss();
                        handler.sendEmptyMessage(2);
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

}
```

**My Logcat are :**

```
E/CustomActivityOnCrash: App has crashed, executing CustomActivityOnCrash's UncaughtExceptionHandler

java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider/-1/1/content://media/external/file/107745/ORIGINAL/NONE/2008282015 flg=0x1 clip={text/uri-list U:content://com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider/-1/1/content%3A%2F%2Fmedia%2Fexternal%2Ffile%2F107745/ORIGINAL/NONE/2008282015} }} to activity {com.aspeage.jagteraho/com.aspeage.jagteraho.ProfileActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object android.os.Bundle.get(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3699)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3742)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap16(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1393)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object android.os.Bundle.get(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
at com.aspeage.jagteraho.ProfileActivity.onActivityResult(ProfileActivity.java:143)
at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6456)
at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3695)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3742) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap16(ActivityThread.java) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1393) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: did u add read external storage permissions ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @quicklearner  yes i did...

Comment: However, [this might be a better dup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10533280/data-in-onactivityresult-is-null)?

Comment: @KenY-N: NO its not the same question anyways thanks for your kind reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this code :

```
if (requestCode == LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {

        bitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data"); //I am Getting Error At This LIne
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        int index = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        imagePath = cursor.getString(index);
        cursor.close();
        profileImageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath));
    }
```

to this

```
if (requestCode == LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {

        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        int index = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        imagePath = cursor.getString(index);
        cursor.close();
        profileImageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath));
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath); 
    }
```

Add your variable `bitmap` at last and set value `bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath);` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
/*
 * Capturing Camera Image will lauch camera app requrest image capture
 */
private void captureImage() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

    fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);

    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);

    // start the image capture Intent
    startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE);
}



/**
 * Receiving activity result method will be called after closing the camera
 * */
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // if the result is capturing Image
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // successfully captured the image
            // display it in image view
            previewCapturedImage();
        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            // user cancelled Image capture
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "User cancelled image capture", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        } else {
            // failed to capture image
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Sorry! Failed to capture image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }
    }
}

/*
     * Display image from a path to ImageView
     */
    private void previewCapturedImage() {
        try {
            // hide video preview
            videoPreview.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            imgPreview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            // bimatp factory
            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();

            // downsizing image as it throws OutOfMemory Exception for larger
            // images
            options.inSampleSize = 8;

            final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fileUri.getPath(),
                    options);

            imgPreview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you please suggest by looking at my code where i should place this code and which part i should remove from my code.

Comment: displayProfileImageClicked(); replace with  captureImage() And onActivity result replace with new one

Answer (score 0):

Even though you are trying to set the bitmap object at that point, you are not anyways using it anywhere. I think you could remove that line. You are using the image path from the content resolver anyways to get the image. If you still want to store to the bitmap member variable, after you have set the imagepath

```
bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath)
```

Comment: Happy to have helped