# intent value null in onActivityResult method of the fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-intent, android-fileprovider

I started working on capturing cam image using file provider. My fragment calls cam capture intent as per the android docs related to [take image simply](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html).

The issue is in `onActivityResult` method intent returns null. Here is how I set everything. I am not able to figure out what I am doing wrong.

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
 <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_path" />
  </provider>
```

**file_path.xml**

```
<paths>
    <external-files-path name="my_images" />
</paths>
```

Implementation on camcapture intent in **Fragment.class**

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    File photoFile = null;

    try {
        photoFile = Utils.createImageFile(getContext());
        String authorities = context.getPackageName()+".fileprovider";
        uriForFile = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, authorities, photoFile);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Log.d(TAG, "handleCaptureImage: "+uriForFile); // shows this result in logs content://appid.fileprovider/my_images/Pictures/JPEG_20170918_181145_719404055.jpg
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uriForFile);
    startActivityForResult(intent, OPEN_CAMERA);
```

**onActivityResult in fragment**

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

        if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE) {
            try {
                //works fine bitmap generated correctly.
                Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getActivity().getContentResolver(), data.getData());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else if (requestCode == OPEN_CAMERA) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult: "+data); //data always null
        }
    }
}
```

I tried calling onActivityResult() in hosting activity as but same result. Need pointer in right direction.. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you set the result while coming back to the same activity or fragment? **setResult(RESULT_OK, intent)** and then finish you activity.

Comment: yes.. it doesnt help.. plus I am in fragment and I just want captured images result so in between I dont need to finish the activity

Answer (score 0):

This will be helpful 
[data in onActivityResult is null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10533280/data-in-onactivityresult-is-null)

And If data.getData() returns null then try:

```
    Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
    Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
```

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I tried this but as per the docs it just gives the thumbnail image and I want to work with the full sized image.

Comment: You can use the other method which you used in the code above and pass getExtras intead of get data.